# How to write multiline Scripts in PowerShell ? I tried using Backtick also but didnt work

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$secPassword = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
New-ADUser
    -Name "XYZ ABC"
    -SamAccountName xyz.a
    -UserPrincipalName "xyz.a@ntsh.local"
    -AccountPassword $secPassword
    -Path "cn=Users,dc=ntsh,dc=local"
    -Enabled:$true
    -PasswordNeverExpires:$true
    -CannotChangePassword:$true
    -PasswordNotRequired:$false
    -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$false
```

It's giving CommandNotFoundException Error for all Parameters. What's wrong in my script ?

Comment: Backtick does work but it's kinda brittle as there must be no whitespace between backtick and the end of the line. Best practice is to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.3#splatting-with-hash-tables) instead.

Comment: And the way you have now set this up, there would be an error in `-SamAccountName xyz.a`. You need to quote the value, so `-SamAccountName 'xyz.a'`. Anyway, [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74419902/how-to-write-multiline-scripts-in-powershell-i-tried-using-backtick-also-but-d#comment131375566_74419902) is correct. You should always use splatting on cmdlets that take a lot of parameters IMO.

Comment: @zett42 That's cool. I now did it with splatting also. It 's a cleaner way. @Theo Yes I got this also that I was missing " " quotes. And also I need to put a Backtick and that should be after at least a space. For eg. ```New-ADUser ` ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the CMDLET in a single line, because it treats them as if they were foreign commands, and the second way if you want to leave it curious, would be to add the symbol `` ` `` so that the cmdlet detects that it continues in the next line

The first way:

```
$secPassword = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
New-ADUser -Name "XYZ ABC" -SamAccountName xyz.a -UserPrincipalName "xyz.a@ntsh.local" -AccountPassword $secPassword -Path "cn=Users,dc=ntsh,dc=local" -Enabled:$true -PasswordNeverExpires:$true -CannotChangePassword:$true -PasswordNotRequired:$false -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$false
```

The second way:

```
$secPassword = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
New-ADUser -Name "XYZ ABC" `
 -SamAccountName xyz.a `
 -UserPrincipalName "xyz.a@ntsh.local" `
 -AccountPassword $secPassword `
 -Path "cn=Users,dc=ntsh,dc=local" `
 -Enabled:$true `
 -PasswordNeverExpires:$true `
 -CannotChangePassword:$true `
 -PasswordNotRequired:$false `
 -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$false
```

Comment: Using line-ending `\`` for line-continuation is effective, but can you explain what you mean by _because it treats them as if they were foreign commands_?

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, splatting is the cleanest way to code as per Zett42's suggestion:

```
$NADUArgs = @{
    Name                  = "XYZ ABC"
    SamAccountName        = "xyz.a"
    UserPrincipalNam      = "xyz.a@ntsh.local"
    AccountPassword       = $secPassword
    Path                  = "cn=Users,dc=ntsh,dc=local"
    Enabled               = $true
    PasswordNeverExpires  = $true
    CannotChangePassword  = $true
    PasswordNotRequired   = $false
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
}

New-ADUser @NADUArgs
```